# What does foremost do that is different from mount?

Tags: linux, mount, dd, forensics

I was doing a [challenge on picoCTF](https://ctftime.org/task/7319) which involved getting a flag from a `.dd` file. The `.dd` file initially appears to be a `FAT` partition that contains some `jpg` files.

My idea was to mount the file using `mount` and check the resultant files. I get four files as a result, and none of them are the flag, just pictures of animals.

The solution was a tool called [foremost](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Foremost), when I used it on the file it extracted eight files instead of four. One of these files was the flag, and the other seven were animals.

What are these tools doing differently? Did `mount` ignore pieces of information in the `.dd` file that `foremost` was able to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` mounted the filesystem and gave you access to files in a usual way provided by the filesystem, by examining directory tree and metadata defining files.

`foremost` is

> a console program to recover files based on their headers, footers, and internal data structures

which means it tries to locate and retrieve files regardless of metadata; this includes files that have been deleted but their content not overwritten yet.

Note the challenge name is "*Recovering* From the Snap".

Comment: In FAT it's often very easy because files that have been deleted don't even lose their metadata at that point – the only thing they lose is the 1st letter of the filename, the OS doesn't bother overwriting anything else. (Anyone remember MS-DOS `undelete`?)

Comment: @grawity That I didn't know, thank you. I made the answer community wiki as an invitation for you to improve it.